# Homography using 3 parallel lines and 1 perpendicular line

Tags: homography

I have been working on a homography problem where the only known real world coordinates are the length between the parallel lines. For corn, the length between the rows is exactly 30 inches. Given an image of crop rows, I need to be able to find the distance between any two points in the real world. I am implementing the solutions by Elan Dubofrosky in his paper, [Homography Estimation](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/msc-ufpe-thesis/blob/master/referencias/Dubrofsky.Elan.Homography.Estimation.pdf), for creating a homography using only lines. I have implemented his methods and I have gotten very good results when estimating the position of real world coordinates on a ping pong table using only lines.

However, when I try to do the same with rows of corn plants, I receive illogical answers as a result. I have added a line to serve as a constraint, such that my lines I can work with would look as such: [camera lines](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ntjluoiz0v). And my real world lines I have inputted look like this: [real world lines](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m5q6bejnt4). Finding points along the first line results in very strange results, such that a point 100 units up the line only results in a difference of 1.5 inches. I know the homography can work when you have lines that form a box, and I have demonstrated such, but is it possible to also create a homography using the set of lines as shown above, with three parallel and one perpendicular, or does it require additional information? Thanks in advance.